# Asynchronously send data over multiple sockets in Python

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous

I am trying to wrap my head around asynchronous code in Python. I have been reading about coroutines and async/await statements but at the end of the day, I am still a little lost. I thought I would do this through an example:

I have different servers listening on different ports at different destinations. I'd like to execute the following function asynchronously (as in to send data to all of them at the same time, since they would be I/O bound).

```
def send_current_elements(current_list):
    for msg in current_list:
        data, destination = msg
        ip, port = (destination['ip'], destination['port'])
        socket = PIRSocket()
        socket.connect((ip,port))
        if type(data).__name__ == 'str':
            data = data.encode()
        s.sendall(data)
        s.close()
```

Adding an async doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
    async def send_current_elements(current_list):
    for msg in current_list:
        data, destination = msg
        ip, port = (destination['ip'], destination['port'])
        socket = PIRSocket()
        socket.connect((ip,port))
        if type(data).__name__ == 'str':
            data = data.encode()
        socket.sendall(data)
        socket.close()
```

Help would be much appreciated to help me understand this.

Also, PIRSocket is just a wrapper around a normal socket which prepends the message with its length before sending.